# create date folder with bash

Tags: linux, bash, date

I created a simple script to to create a folder with the name as the date

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=$(date +"%d%m%y")

mkdir /mnt/storage/Backup\ Archive/$DATE
```

and running it from cron

```
05 00 * * * /usr/local/sbin/makedate
```

It works but sometimes at random it create a file instead of a folder?

Comment: There's no way that `mkdir` will create a file. Something else must be going on. Add some debugging to the script. Check for that path before running `mkdir`. Check the path after. Catch the return from `mkdir` for errors. etc.

Comment: @etanreisner is dead on.  My guess, and it is just that, there is already a regular file out there created before the mkdir command ran.  Does your makedate script log errors somewhere? Check there. The user who owns the crontab should get mail from the cron daemon if no logging of stderr.

Comment: Your date format doesn't sort well.  You might prefer `%y%m%d` (if you have dates before 2000, use `%Y%m%d`). Regarding the actual problem I suspect @jimmcnamara and Etan Reisner have it: there's another script creating these files *first*, then `makedate` fails to create the directory because a file with the same name already exists. Check your mail spool, you should see some errors in there.

Comment: You should quote `"$DATE"`.  Even though that `date` format can't output spaces, it's good practice to always quote things unless you specifically *do* want them to be word-split and so on after expansion.